# JupyterHub - how to create a new username and set password?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, jupyterhub

I just installed JupyterHub on Linux RHEL 7 and once started (with root) a JupyterHub - it ask for user/pass.

What are correct steps to set some user and password for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which authenticator you are using, but it sounds like you did a fairly standard installation, so you're probably using the PAM authenticator. This pretty much means you're using a system's user's credentials.

so, create a user on your server

```sh
sudo adduser nick
```

and go through the steps to create the user. Once you do that you can log in using the user you just created. Want a different log in? New user!

Other authenticators will be different, that is just for PAM authentication which is the simplest.

Check out your other options here: https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started/authenticators-users-basics.html#use-oauthenticator-to-support-oauth-with-popular-service-providers